# Method is printing out the wrong percentage integer

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, java.util.scanner, outputstream

From this program I am creating an array and finding the total number of letter characters and finding a percentages of the total letters from A-D. I created a method that enables me to find the percentage of a character appears in a sequence.

For example for an array of AABD the character A would be 50% of the array. I have tested this method out and it mostly works until I try the character D in which I inexplicably get a 26 instead of a 30% which confuses me.

The data I am using is from this data text is this down below which ignores letters not between A-D
I am trying to print out a percentage of 30 from the method but I keep getting 26 and I am unsure why

Example #1:

```
AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD
AAEBCBAFBBCDCECDADDEFEEFFF
```

Example #2:

```
AAATAABTBBBBCCCCTCDDTDDD
AASAABBSBBCCSCCDSDDDEEEAEEFBFFFDDF
```

My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class findSequence {
    public static int findPercentages(int perNum, int totalNum) {   
        int percent = (int) Math.round(perNum * 100.0 / totalNum);
        return percent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("ShortData.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("newDNAOutput");         
        PrintStream outputStream = null;

        Scanner fileScan = null;

        try {
            fileScan = new Scanner(inputFile);
            outputStream = new PrintStream(outputFile); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found " + e);
            System.out.println("Exiting program");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int numA = 0;
        int numB = 0;
        int numC = 0;
        int numD = 0;

        while(fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            String theLine = fileScan.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(theLine);

            if(theLine.length() > 10) {
                theLine = theLine.toUpperCase();
                char[] dnaArray = new char[theLine.length()];

                for(int j = 0; j < dnaArray.length; j++) {
                    dnaArray[j] = theLine.charAt(j);
                }

                Arrays.sort(dnaArray);

                for(int i = 0; i < dnaArray.length; i++) {
                    if(dnaArray[i] == 'A') {
                        numA = numA + 1;

                    }

                    if(dnaArray[i] == 'B') {
                        numB = numB + 1;
                    }

                    if(dnaArray[i] == 'C') {
                        numC = numC + 1;
                    }

                    if(dnaArray[i] == 'D') {
                        numD = numD + 1;
                    }
                }

                int totalSum = numA + numB + numC + numD;

                int numAPer = findPercentages(numA, totalSum);
                int numBPer = findPercentages(numB, totalSum);
                int numCPer = findPercentages(numC, totalSum);
                int numDPer = findPercentages(numD, totalSum);

                outputStream.println(numDPer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: read about proper Java code indentation. You should put your { braces at the end of a line, and be consistent about using always the same indentation. Such things matter. They make your code easy to read, or hard to read.

Comment: Put your declarations of `numA`, `numB` and the rest inside of the `while` loop. At the start of each iteration of the loop after the first iteration, the variables still hold the values they held at the end of the previous iteration. Which is not what I think you want.

Comment: Another side note: there is no point in sorting the array. It has no effect on your result. In fact, when you omit the sorting, copying the string into an array becomes obsolete too. You can iterate over the string the same way you do when filling the array and count the characters in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have 20 Ds in 76 characters (excluding the two *a*s in the words *Example #1* and *Example #2*). That's a percentage of: 26.31578947368421, roughly 26%. If you want to go for the 30% you should have a total of around 66 characters.

To have the percentage of each line you just need to move the declarations of the letter count inside the `while` loop:

```
while(fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
int numA = 0;
int numB = 0;
int numC = 0;
int numD = 0;

String theLine = fileScan.nextLine();

if(theLine.length() > 10) {
    theLine = theLine.toUpperCase();
    char[] dnaArray = new char[theLine.length()];

    for(int j = 0; j < dnaArray.length; j++) {
        dnaArray[j] = theLine.charAt(j);
    }

    Arrays.sort(dnaArray);

    for (char c : dnaArray) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'A':
                numA += 1;
                break;
            case 'B':
                numB += 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
                numC += 1;
                break;
            case 'D':
                numD += 1;
                break;
        }
    }

    int totalSum = numA + numB + numC + numD;

    int numAPer = findPercentages(numA, totalSum);
    int numBPer = findPercentages(numB, totalSum);
    int numCPer = findPercentages(numC, totalSum);
    int numDPer = findPercentages(numD, totalSum);

    outputStream.println(numDPer);
}
```

}

This will clear the values each time the loop runs.

Comment: I see, I'm trying to find the percentage of each line so for the 4th line i was hoping that it would calculate 6/20 = 30% I suppose I should've made that more clear. My question is how would i get it to calculate for only one line? At a time?

Comment: @Rengoku, I've edited my answer to answer your question.